# Add numbers and then sumif in excel

Tags: excel, sumifs

What I want to do but can't see how can I do it:

```
=SUMIF(600 - C:C,A:A,"=--")
```

I want to sum the difference between 600 and the actual number, only if my the A column matches `--`

Currently I've created an extra column to hold the result of 600 - the C column, but I want to simplify my sheet.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will want to use SUMPRODUCT() and limit the range to the actual dataset:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((600-C2:C28)*(A2:A28="--"))
```

**OR**

If you want to avoid the array formula and keep the full column references then use this:

```
=(600*COUNTIF(A:A,"=--"))-SUMIF(A:A,"=--",C:C)
```

[image]

Comment: very cute ... and clever solution :)

Comment: Thanks, with your help I wrote this:

=(I6 * COUNTIFS(B:B,"<"&I6,B:B,">0",A:A,"<>--")) - SUMIFS(B:B,B:B,"<"&I6,B:B,">0",A:A,"<>--")